# Why round() make my expression give wrong answer?

Tags: c++

I'm currently facing a problem but I don't know why it wrong?

```cpp
// ll ís long long

ll cnt = 24822089714520516;

cout << "xpow: " << xpow(10LL, 16) << endl;
cout << "cnt: " << cnt << endl;

ll a = xpow(10LL, 16) + cnt - 1;
ll b = round(xpow(10LL, 16)) + cnt - 1;

cout << "cur_num (without round): " << a << endl;
cout << "cur_num (with round): " << b << endl;
```

with `xpow` is defined by myself:

```cpp
ll xpow(ll a, ll b) {
  ll ans = 1;
  while (b) {
    if (b & 1)
      ans *= a;
    b >>= 1;
    if (b)
      a *= a;
  };
  return ans;
};
```

When I run my code, I get this log:

```
xpow: 10000000000000000
cnt: 24822089714520516
cur_num (without round): 34822089714520515
cur_num (with round): 34822089714520516
```

As you see, my result if I use round is differenced with one when I don't round (smaller than 1 unit)

It may be my computer's problem, but may be no. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks so much!

Comment: [`round()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) is to dealing with floating-point values. They may not have enough precision to handle such large value precisely.

Comment: Use `int64_t`, not `long long` or the horrible macro `ll`.

Comment: Please don't use aliases (or even worse, macros) for standard types. Those makes the code much harder to read and understand (and therefore maintain). Such aliases are typically show-cased on so-called "competition" sites which are only good for showing really bad programming habits.

Comment: That right, I also think it is a bad programming habits. But this code is a piece of my code in my last competitive contest :V

Comment: Ye, I know it. Because before using xpow (is defined by myself), I used pow (builtin function) so I must use round to prevent floating-point problem. After that I tried to define xpow, and randomly run my code while coding, I get this problem. So I tried to find a solution, and post here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many C++ implementations, the `long long` type is 64 bits long, and the `double` type is 64 bits long. When this happens, a variable of type `double` cannot exactly represent all possible `long long` values, and in particular large `long long` values might be approximated incorrectly by a `double`.

Here, `round` converts your `long long` to a `double`, introducing some imprecision.

Comment: Maybe worth to note that although a `double` is 64 bits, only 53 bits can be stored in the mantissa, so a `int64_t` can lose up to 11 bits of precision.

Comment: @prapin Thanks for pointing that out!